# set android notification on a date from date picker

Tags: android, notifications

i have an android with a date picker.
i would like to choose a date and save it with an action bar item.
at this moment, it should be set an notification with the selected date.

this is my first time with notifications.
can everybody tell me, how i realize this?
i use min. SDK 15

i try something like this, but with this the notification start directly:

```
intent = new Intent(this, Overview.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    long[] pattern = {200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200};
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("My Titel")
            .setContentText("This is the Body")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a notification it should notify at n date you need to use a broadcast receiver and because a broadcast receiver up only for a short time its a better practice to use also intent service here you have a example how to do it.

this is the broadcast receiver class.

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);

        context.startService(intent1);

}
```

}

and register it in the manifest.

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
    </receiver>
```

this is the intent service class.

```
public class MyNewIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 3;

public MyNewIntentService() {
    super("MyNewIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
   Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("My Titel");
        builder.setContentText("This is the Body");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_appicon);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
    NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);

}
```

}
 and register it in the manifest.

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyNewIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
```

and then in your activity set the alarm manger to start the broadcast receiver at a specific date like this this example use the date picker to help you with that:

```
   DatePicker datePicker= (DatePicker)timeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
```

and:

```
   Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

now.set(now.get( datePicker.getYear()), now.get(datePicker.getMonth()), now.get(datePicker.getDayOfMonth()), the hour, and the minute);
            if(now.compareTo(current)<=0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"invalid time",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
 Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("title",item.getText());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (context, NOTIFICATION_REMINDER, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,now.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

}

i hope this will help you!

Comment: thx. but what do you mean with " a broadcast receiver up only for a short time "?

Comment: from the google docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle

Comment: from the android developer blog.When handling a broadcast, the application is given a fixed set of time (currently 10 seconds) in which to do its work. If it doesn't complete in that time, the application is considered to be misbehaving, and its process immediately tossed into the background state to be killed for memory if needed.

Comment: okay, and is there an way to show all notifications, which i had set?

Comment: i dont understand you want to set a few different notifications or just one and it should repeat every day or something like that?

Comment: if you mean to different tittle etc just sent it with putExtra with the intent and create a intent based on the conditions and get the extra and set the tittle etc with that dies it make scene for you?